# How to install Rails on an EC2 server?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ruby-on-rails

I have installed Rails on my localhost, and now, I would like to install it on an Amazon EC2 server.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it for you pretty much.  It is a deployment tool writtne specifically for EC2 - and its called EC2 on rails.

http://ec2onrails.rubyforge.org/

Answer (score 0):

Ssh into your ec2 instance and run:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.9.1-full
sudo gem install rails
```

Done.